# How to use jest.spyOn with React function component using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

I am developing a React app using Typescript, and hooks, and I am trying to use Enzyme with Jest to test the function components. I am unable to use jest.spyOn to test a method in my component. The jest.spyOn method doesn't resolve correctly and shows following message on hover

> "Argument of type '"validateBeforeSave"' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '"context" | "setState" | "forceUpdate" | "render" |
>   "componentDidMount" | "shouldComponentUpdate" | "componentWillUnmount"
>   | "componentDidCatch" | "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate" | ... 6 more ... |
>   "UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate"'.ts(2345)"

I tried to cast the instance as 'Any' -

```
const instance = wrapper.instance() as any;
```

This of course ignores the problem at compile time, but then the test throws a runtime error that function does not exist on component.

> Cannot spy the validateBeforeSave property because it is not a
>   function; undefined given instead

```
// Some function Component

const SomeComponent = (props: IMyComponentProps) => {
  const { classes } = props;

  // Component has state
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function validateBeforeSave(){

  }

  function handleClick() {
  validateBeforeSave();
  .
  .
  .
  }

  return (
   <div>
      <Button>
      className="saveBtn"
      onClick={handleClick}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );

  };

  // Unit test
  describe('SomeComponent' () => {
  it('validates model on button click', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <SomeComponent/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
      );
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
      const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, "validateBeforeSave");
  wrapper
        .find('.saveBtn')
        .at(0)
        .simulate('click');
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  }
```

What am I missing here? How does spyOn work with function components?

I created the app using the create-react-app template and it has these dependencies for test packages

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.3",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.9",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.9.1",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.11.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `validateBeforeSave` function is declared within `SomeComponent` making it a closed/private scope function not accessible outside. You can pass that function as a prop and you can then create spy and pass it as a prop value in your test and test for if the prop function passed (spy) was called or not

So you would modify your function somewhat like this:

```
// some validator function
function validateBeforeSave(){
  ...
}

// Some function Component

const SomeComponent = (props: IMyComponentProps) => {
  const { classes, validateBeforeSave } = props;

  // Component has state
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


  function handleClick() {
  validateBeforeSave();
  .
  .
  .
  }

  return (
   <div>
      <Button>
      className="saveBtn"
      onClick={handleClick}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );

};
```

And In your Unit test, something like this:

```
  // Unit test
  describe('SomeComponent' () => {
  it('validates model on button click', () => {
      const validateSpy = jest.fn();
      const wrapper = mount(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <SomeComponent validateSpy={validateSpy}/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
      );
      const instance = wrapper.instance();
      wrapper
        .find('.saveBtn')
        .at(0)
        .simulate('click');
      expect(validateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, we can't spyOn a function inside a function component. But why do I get the type error when I try to provide a function as a parameter in spyOn? I have to cast my instance as 'any' as shown above, otherwise I get the compile error as shown above (Argument of type..). I am unable to use spyOn method, the only arguments it likes for the method param are the ones shown in the error message above ('"context" | "setState" | "forceUpdate" ..etc). Which means I can't spyOn on any random method even if it passed as props. I should be using Jest.fn I guess

Comment: Yes I changed the implementation to jest.fn() in my code. You can still use spyOn if you are importing that function from somewhere and then do assert on it.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem mocking callback prop method with React 16.x.x, enzyme instance method returns null, what you can do is pass directly jest.fn() as a prop.

EXAMPLE:

```
  it('should invoke callback with proper data upon checkbox click', () => {
    const spyCheckboxClick = jest.fn((id, item) => ({
      id,
      item,
    }))
    const component: any = enzyme.mount(
      <SectionColumn {...{
        ...mockProps,
        onCheckboxClick: spyCheckboxClick,
      }} />
    );
    expect(spyCheckboxClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    // perform click to checkbox
    const checkboxComponent = component.find('StyledCheckbox');
    const input = checkboxComponent.first().children();
    input.simulate('change');
    expect(spyCheckboxClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spyCheckboxClick()).toEqual(null)
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

I was also facing the same issue - I did like below -

```
import * as React from 'react';

const SampleComponent = () => {
  const sampleMethod = () => {
    console.log('hello world');
  };

  return <button onClick={sampleMethod} type="button">Click Me</button>;
};

export default SampleComponent;
```

test -

```
import React from 'react';
import SampleComponent from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
  test('should handle click correctly', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent></SampleComponent>);
    const button = wrapper.find('button');
    expect(button.text()).toBe('Click Me');
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('hello world');
  });
});
```

We can spy on console.log, to assert it is to be called or not

Check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637912/10734622

Comment: but this solution is to spy console.log inside the functional component not the `sampleMethod` itself.

Comment: this is for console log